# Comparar valor de un select con un valor de un input usando if-else

Tags: php, formularios

Soy novato programando en PHP y necesito hacer un formulario usando if- else donde el usuario ingrese el valor de un producto y elija un plan de pago de un select para calcular las tesas de interés y el monto total.

Los planes son los siguientes:

- panel A iteres 10%
- panel B interés 20%
- panel C interés 34%
- panel D interés sin interés

Éste es el código del formulario:

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="GET">

<select name="opciones" id="">
  <option value="plan1">Plan A</option>
  <option value="plan2">Plan B</option>
  <option value="plan3">Plan C</option>
  <option value="plan4">Plan D</option>
</select>

<br>

Ingrese el monto:
<input type="number" name="dinero"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">

</form>
```

Y el código PHP que lo procesa:

```
<?php

$costo = $_POST["dinero"]."<br>";
$opciones = $_POST["opciones"];

if ($opciones == "plan1") {

  $resultado1 = $costo *10/100;
  $total = $resultado1 + $costo;

  echo "El interes es: ".$resultado3"El valor total es: ".$total;;
}
else ($opciones == "plan2") {

  $resultado2 = $costo *20/100;
  $total = $resultado2 + $costo;

  echo "El interes es: ".$resultado2"El valor total es: ".$total;;

}
else ($opciones == "plan3") {

  $resultado3 = $costo *34/100;
  $total = $resultado3 + $costo;

  echo "El interes es: ".$resultado3. "El valor total es: ".$total;

}
else ($opciones == "plan4") {

  echo "Sin Interes";
?>
```

Comment: Hola Sora Kasugano, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Hola Sora Kasugano, además de lo que indica KacosPro, sería ideal que añadieras los mensajes de error que recibes al ejecutar el código (si no ves ninguno, pon `error_reporting(E_ALL);` al principio de tu código PHP). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

**ERRORES DE SINTÁXIS DETECTADOS TE RECOMIENDO LEER LAS ACLARACIONES QUE TE HARÉ**

> Estas aplicandolo mal, si tienes mas de una opción para hacer
>   comparaciones no deberías usar else; si no else if para indicar que
>   puedes comparar con mas opciones posibles, cuando ya no tienes mas
>   escenarios por comparar y darás una respuesta por defecto entonces si
>   aplica else, además de que al else de hasta el final le faltaba una llave por cerrar

```
<?php

$costo = $_POST["dinero"]."<br>";
$opciones = $_POST["opciones"];

if ($opciones == "plan1") {

$resultado1 = $costo *10/100;
$total = $resultado1 + $costo;

echo "El interes es: ".$resultado3."El valor total es: ".$total;
}
else if($opciones == "plan2") {

$resultado2 = $costo *20/100;
$total = $resultado2 + $costo;

echo "El interes es: ".$resultado2."El valor total es: ".$total;

}

else if($opciones == "plan3") {

$resultado3 = $costo *34/100;
$total = $resultado3 + $costo;

echo "El interes es: ".$resultado3. "El valor total es: ".$total;

}


else if($opciones == "plan4") {

echo "Sin Interes";
}else{
echo "Opción desconocida";  
}
```

Otro error que noto es que al momento de concatenar una variable entre cadenas de texto no estas haciéndolo de ambos lados, es decir al concatenar así debes poner un punto justo antes y después de la variable; de este modo `.$name.` y finalmente tenías doble punto y coma en algunos renglones

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría un SWITCH, es más elegante y queda mejor a la vista:

```
<?php

$costo = $_POST["dinero"]."<br>";
$opciones = $_POST["opciones"];

switch ($opciones)
{
  case "plan1":
    $resultado1 = $costo *10/100;
    $total = $resultado1 + $costo;
    echo "El interes es: ".$resultado3"El valor total es: ".$total;
    break;

  case "plan2":
    $resultado2 = $costo *20/100;
    $total = $resultado2 + $costo;
    echo "El interes es: ".$resultado2"El valor total es: ".$total;
    break;

  case "plan3":
    $resultado3 = $costo *34/100;
    $total = $resultado3 + $costo;
    echo "El interes es: ".$resultado3. "El valor total es: ".$total;
    break;

  //El default se realiza cuando no se ha introducido ninguno de los 
  //anteriores, como puede ser el plan4
  default:
    echo "Sin Interés";
    break;
}
?>
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Seria lo ideal pero me pide que use específicamente if-else para luego sacar las comisiones de las ventas que serian:

Para importes menores de $ 500, el 5 % del importe
Para importes iguales o mayores que a $ 500, pero menores a $ 1000, el 7 % del importe.
Para importe mayores o iguales a $ 10000, el 8 % mas $ 6 Pesos

y si no me equivoco entonces quedaria algo asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ejercicio 3</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="enviar.php" method="GET">

Ingrese el monto:

<input type="number" name="comision"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>

</body>
</html>

//PHP//

<?php

$comision = $_POST["comision"]."<br>";


if ($comision < 500) {

$resultado1 = $comision *5/100;

echo "La comision es: ".$resultado3;
}
else if($comision >= 500 && <1000) {

$resultado2 = $comision *7/100;

echo "La comision es: ".$resultado2;

}

else if($comision >= 10000) {

$resultado3 = $comision *8/100 + 6;

echo "La comision es: ".$resultado3;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de publicar el error que te esta mandando pero, he detectado algo:

```
$comision = $_POST["comision"]."<br>";
```

Estas añadiendo un tag HTML al final de tu variable y luego la estas comparando en los IF-ELSE con números, ejemplo: suponiendo que tu variable $_POST["comision"] tenga el valor de 500 la comparación quedaría así siguiendo tu código:

```
if("500<br>" < 500)...
```

intenta asignar el valor en tu variable $comision sin el "
":

```
$comision = $_POST["comision"];
```